# Why can't I use jQuery selectors from WebDriver's CssSelector if jQuery is loaded on the page I'm testing?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a page on which jQuery is loaded, using WebDriver and ChromeDriver. I'd like to use some jQuery selectors, particularly the `:contains()` pseudo-selector for finding a node based on the text in that node. However, when I try to pass selector strings that use jQuery selectors like `:contains()` or `:has()` into WebDriver's `By.CssSelector()` method, WebDriver throws an invalid argument exception. I thought that ChromeDriver just passed the CSS selector through to the underlying browser. Can anyone explain exactly where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Selenium uses its own implementation, based on [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), as describe in [this blog post](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/01/why-jquery-in-selenium-css-locators-is-the-way-to-go/comment-page-1/) and [this one on WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html).

You can always use the [JavaScript Executor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) to use jQuery to find elements:

```
script = "return $('"+selector+"').get(0);"
element = webdriver.execute_script(script);
```

Code example from [this blog post](http://serebrov.github.io/html/2012-08-02-selenium-webdriver-element-by-jquery-selector.html). Update it for the programming language you are using.

[Here is an example in Java](http://rajchel.pl/2014/07/finding-elements-jquery-selenium/), which also injects jQuery if it is not yet loaded by the website itself.

Comment: Thanks - those were some informative posts. So it sounds from the first link like they actually don't use Sizzle in Selenium 2, as a deliberate choice to improve performance and instead rely on the native browser CSS support. That does match what I've seen when sending paths to WebDriver for parsing.